# can i say "operate a programing language"?

Tags: word-usage

I've heard usages like "operate a programing language" from another non-native English speaker. And it sounds odd to me, especially for the verb "operate" here. Even though it's grammatically correct and I pretty much knew he meant "use" by "operate".

I wondering whether native speaker would  find this usage correct or accurate enough. And if not, would there be a better alternative than "use" for "operate".

Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard it. Normally you "program in a programming language" or even "write in a programming language" (more commonly something like, "I wrote that in Haskell"). Google responds 'No results found for +"operate a programming language"', which oddly enough should have caught this question.

Comment: "Operate" doesn't make sense in connection with programming languages, though it is clear what that person meant by it. "Use" in okay: "Have you used Haskell?" or "I'll use C++ for this application."

Comment: You could operate a computer (a very common usage) and in a less common usage might operate a compiler or IDE or other piece of software (an operator is a common term for someone who uses a computer for basic, low-level work such as data entry). But generally operate is used for physically interacting with tangible things like computers, not abstract things like languages.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Try English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English speaker I would find it strange if someone used this wording.

I am also a programmer, I would say I can write in a particular language.

In a sentence I would say it like this: "I can write in several programming languages."

Its akin to saying I can write in German or French.

Comment: Write, code, and use.